# OpenGL drawing several objects

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo, opengl-3

How usually people draw several objects in OpenGL 3.3+? 
I have 2 objects: a terrain and a sphere. For each object i have 2 arrays(of vertices and indices). I tried to set different VBO and IBO(like this):

```
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*)12);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*)20);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_IBO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (size-1)*(size-1)*6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);



    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBOsphere);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_IBOsphere);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

but looks like GPU calculates/draw everything only after closing of this function and I see only a sphere. So, what should I do?

Comment: I don't see any problems here. Just to make sure, if you comment out 3 lines of spheres rendering, terrain is rendered fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you misunderstood the implications of binding a buffer, and the correct sequence of calls.

You expected that in this sequence, the draw call would get its vertices from the VBO with id `m_VBO`:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_IBO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (size-1)*(size-1)*6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

That's not the way it works. The current `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding has absolutely no effect on the draw call.

You need to have the right VBO bound when `glVertexAttribPointer()` is called. Beyond the direct arguments that specify values for the setup of the corresponding attribute (format, stride, etc), this call also specifies that the **currently bound** VBO is used as the source for the attribute data.

Therefore, you need the `glVertexAttribPointer()` calls for each object, and call them **after** binding the corresponding VBO.

The call sequence is then:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*)12);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*)20);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_IBO);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (size-1)*(size-1)*6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBOsphere);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*)12);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid*)20);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_IBOsphere);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
```

If you want to reduce the number of setup calls you need before each draw call, look up Vertex Array Objects (VAO).